# Function in JS not showing any output. I cant see any error either

Tags: javascript

I am facing a new issue now. My function in JaveScript is not prompt for input. Also, there is no error.

```js
function greetings (Name) {
    var result = "Hello" + " " + Name;
    console.log(result);

var your_name = prompt("What is your name?");
greetings(your_name);

}



function guess (My_Age) {
    var result = 'I guess your age is' + ' ' + My_Age;
    console.log(result);

var age = prompt ("What is my Age?");
guess(age);
}
```

[image]

Comment: my email is tauqeerahmad104@gmail.com   inside of question is the wrong email.

Comment: Please follow the guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your front end app should talk to the backend over HTTP.

You front end app will make an HTTP request to your backend server. The HTTP request will contain any data the backend needs. This is typically form data from the frontend.

(You could use websockets here too but HTTP is more standard)

The backend, on receiving the HTTP request, will then take appropriate action such as saving to a database. The backend will then respond to the HTTP request with an HTTP response, letting the front end know if the HTTP request was successful (typically HTTP status code 200) or not. The front end can then take action accordingly.

frontend app --- HTTP ----> backend server ---- sql query or something similar ---> Database

Then for the response just reverse the arrows.